# filter through array of objects in ng-repeat angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I am trying to filter an array (list) of repeated objects, based on the value of one of the property. However I keep getting `[filter: not array]` error. Screenshot of the error:
[angular error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03jol.png)

I have also tried adding this angular toArrayFIlter injector https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter however, the error still pops out.

Any help is much appreciated!

My array:

```
var orders = [
{
  "assignedBy": "system",
  "serviceDate":"2017-11-13",
  "serviceStartTime":"04:00 PM"
},
{
  "assignedBy": "system",
  "serviceDate":"2017-11-13",
  "serviceStartTime":"07:00 AM"
}];
```

html

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in orders  track by $index | filter: { serviceStartTime: '04:00 PM' }">  
  <li >
    <p>{{task.serviceDate}}</p>
    <p>{{task.serviceStartTime}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove `track by $index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to filter the array before iterating it, like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="task in (orders | filter: { serviceStartTime: '04:00 PM' }) track by $index ">
```